# Errors when running an imported java zip file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I Imported  a zip java file in eclipse and choose run as ---> run configuration and in VM argumentation tab  added :  -Djava.library.path=lib/java3d-1.6/windows/amd64;lib/yafaray/windows/x64 . so when I run I get Errors ! these are the errors :

```
221117 21:54:01:128 Exception thrown at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.isCanceled(NamedTimer.java:61)
    at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.run(NamedTimer.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516): java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field int java.util.TimerTask.state accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5099f48
    (caught at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.isCanceled(NamedTimer.java:66))
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler$DummyException jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@579bb367
    at abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler$1.run(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:93)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
221117 21:54:01:461 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:115):
    The handler for event dispatch thread exceptions could not be installed
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by abbot.util.SystemState (file:/C:/Users/Jasmin/eclipse-workspace/SweetHome3D/libtest/abbot.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of abbot.util.SystemState
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
221117 21:54:04:372 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:05:451 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:06:376 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:07:803 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:18:832 Exception thrown at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.isCanceled(NamedTimer.java:61)
    at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.run(NamedTimer.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516): java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field int java.util.TimerTask.state accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5099f48
    (caught at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.isCanceled(NamedTimer.java:66))
221117 21:54:24:849: Last message repeated 22 times
221117 21:54:25:824 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:26:569 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:27:516 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:28:114 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:29:076 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:31:324 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:32:288 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.swing.undo.CannotUndoException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.undo.UndoManager.tryUndoOrRedo(UndoManager.java:468)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.undo.UndoManager.undo(UndoManager.java:416)
    at com.eteks.sweethome3d.junit.PlanComponentTest$PlanTestFrame$3.actionPerformed(PlanComponentTest.java:515)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
221117 21:54:33:397 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:35:550 Exception thrown at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.isCanceled(NamedTimer.java:61)
    at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.run(NamedTimer.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516): java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field int java.util.TimerTask.state accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5099f48
    (caught at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.isCanceled(NamedTimer.java:66))
221117 21:54:35:815: Last message repeated 34 times
221117 21:54:37:958 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:40:777 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:41:710 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
221117 21:54:43:070 Exception thrown at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.isCanceled(NamedTimer.java:61)
    at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.run(NamedTimer.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:566)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516): java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field int java.util.TimerTask.state accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5099f48
    (caught at abbot.util.NamedTimer$ProtectingTimerTask.isCanceled(NamedTimer.java:66))
221117 21:54:44:300: Last message repeated 4 times
221117 21:54:44:522 abbot.util.EventDispatchExceptionHandler.install(EventDispatchExceptionHandler.java:74):
    Can't install event dispatch exception handler
```

I expected to see the code is running but that is not the case ! Can anyone tell me please ,how can i solve these Errors ?!What's the Problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The software you are attempting to run does not run on newer JVM versions.

Install a JVM8, for example [Adoptiom JDK8](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=8) and run on that.